# jQuery-Steps OnFinishing event missing CurrentIndex argument

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I am using [jQuery steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/GettingStarted) and everything seems to be working except I want to have a Finish/Save button for all the steps and perform different actions. Although according to its [documentation](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings) the OnFinishing event has currentIndex as its argument, it doesn't look like it's being set probably and when I debug the code it's always undefined. Is there anything I'm missing in the settings?

```
 $("#wizard").steps({
        /* Appearance */
        bodyTag: "section",
        stepsOrientation: 1,//vertical            
        showFinishButtonAlways: true,

        /* Behaviour */
        enableAllSteps: true,
        saveState: true,

        /* Events */
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {                                              
           return true;
        },
        onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) { },
        onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {                
            console.log(currentIndex);                
        },
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
            console.log(currentIndex); 
        },

        /* Labels */
        labels: {
            current: "current step:",
            pagination: "Pagination",
            finish: "Save",
            next: "Next",
            previous: "Previous",
            loading: "Loading ..."
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates your issue? http://jsfiddle.net/